# javascript audio currentTime crashes some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have problem with audio which I am playing in my app. I have HTML audio:

```
    <audio id="correct-sound">
        <source src="sounds/catch.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

then inside my game I have such code

```
    jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).currentTime = 0;
    jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).play();
```

but for some browsers it crashes all script. I have included for older firefox try, catch, but it didn't helped for other some other devices (in Firefox it helped)

```
try{
    jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).currentTime = 0;
    jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).play();
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

The problem is that I cannot replicate that error, but when I removed that code for some browsers this crash was removed. So I just need somehow if there is crash, so they could skip this part and move on, like try catch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work:

```
if (typeof jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).currentTime !== 'undefined') {
  jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).currentTime = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `audio` element is a new HTML5 element and its features do not exist in all browsers. Checkout it's current current support [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

For the time being, I would check if `Audio` exists:

```
if (window.Audio !== undefined) {
    jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).currentTime = 0;
    jQuery('#correct-sound').get(0).play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working in Google Chrome and ran into this problem. Oddly enough in the past I've worked with changing the time in video with no issues, so I knew it was possible.

I seemed to remember a trick where if you set currentTime to a string instead of a number, it works. So I just switched

`audio.currentTime=0;`

to

`audio.currentTime="0";`

And it works now with no problems!

If you're trying to set currentTime to a variable value, try:

`audio.currentTime=String(newTime);`

I'm not sure why `currentTime` has to be set as a string, because if you check an audio clip's `currentTime` value in the console, you'll get a number, not a string. But it works!

EDIT: Interesting and a head-scratcher, if I change currentTime in the console, but set it using a number (not a string) it works. So the way that the console affects currentTime is different than my external JavaScript file, I guess. Changing currentTime to a number in the console works whether or not I've previously changed it to a string.